Configuring elevated or admin privilege in a react native based windows application
I am creating a React Native application for Windows, and I want that my application run with admin privileges, as I have implemented native modules (using C++) that use the Windows API (CreateEvent), which uses a global namespace that needs admin rights.
I tried giving admin permissions to the Package.appxmanifest file in Capabilities, like this: 
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
        <rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
    </Capabilities>

But, this was not of any help.
I have also tried running exe as admin, but there was no option for it.`
I have also got a node-module react-native-permissions, but this was also not working for the RN Windows application. The link that i used for this module is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions
